# Sublassing NSMutableAttributedString returns SIGABRT on init

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsattributedstring

I created a subclass of  NSMutableAttributedString in one of my projects to make a string that continually changes each character to one of the colors given in an array on init, but when I try to call the init method, I get a `sigabrt` on the `initWithString:` method.

#### RainbowString.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface RainbowString : NSMutableAttributedString

@property (nonatomic) NSArray* colors;
@property (nonatomic) NSTimeInterval duration;
@property (nonatomic) NSTimer* timer;

- (id)initStringWithColors:(NSArray*)colors withString:(NSString*)string;
- (id)initStringWithColors:(NSArray*)colors withCycleDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration withString:(NSString*)string;

- (void)stop;
- (void)start:(NSTimeInterval)duration;

@end
```

#### initWithColors:

```
- (id)initStringWithColors:(NSArray *)colors withString:(NSString *)string
{
    self = [super initWithString:string];
    if(self)
    {
        [self setColors:colors];
        [self cycle];
    }

    return self;
}
```

Even if I just call `[[RainbowString alloc] initWithString:@"Hello"];`, I get the same error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[RainbowString initWithString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x166778c0'

### Update

Okay, so just to test this, I created a test subclass of NSMutableAttributedString with absolutely no content. I just created the subclass and left it plain.

#### Test.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Test : NSMutableAttributedString

@end
```

I ran:

```
[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Hello"];
```

That ran and compiled fine. But then I ran:

```
[[Test alloc] initWithString:@"Hello"];
```

Same error. Am I not allowed to subclass NSMutableAttributedString or something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your conclusion is correct. `NS(Mutable)AttributedString` is a [class cluster](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/devpedia-cocoacore/ClassCluster.html), and subclassing those doesn't work. Pity the Apple documentation doesn't clearly identify it as one.

Comment: So how could I go about accomplishing what I had in mind? It's basically an attributed string where every letter is a different color (given an array of UIColors) and they all change every .1 seconds?

Comment: @David - A common approach: design a class which *has a*, as opposed to *is a*, `NS(Mutable)AttributedString`. Indeed if you read the `NSAttributedString` documentation it states that it itself is a wrapper, rather than a subclass, of `NSString`.

Comment: So would I be creating a *new* NSMAS every time the timer fires, or could I just edit the one?

Comment: @David - Strange question. Your design, your choice. Or maybe I'm misunderstanding what you're asking?

Answer (score 0):

For future searchers, [this gist](https://gist.github.com/github-user32/00ad9d1e3cb672bbd79108ed9eb132ee) may be handy. It's a sub-class of NSAttributedString that re-implements the public interface of NSAttributedString via composition - calls to the public methods are passed through to an internal instance of NSAttributedString.

I wouldn't use it for production code, but sometimes it's a useful starting point when you want to temporarily instrument aspects of NSAttributedString during development.